# Strange error in GLM

Tags: error-handling, count, regression, glm, poisson

I'm creating multiple poisson regressions, each model with different outcome. On this particularly outcome which is not different from the others (all binary, either 0 or 1) I get this strange error that I've never seen before.

```
mix_1<- glm(count~ offset(log(time)) + age + gender, data=x[x$diagnosis=="match",], family=poisson)
```

There is nothing wrong with the glm model, I't works as intended. I receive an error when trying to do cbind and exponentiate the coefficients.

```
mix_2 <- cbind(exp(coef(mix_1)), exp(confint(mix_1)))
```

This is the error that I get:

```
   Waiting for profiling to be done...
    Error in glm.fit(x = Xi, y = Y, weights = W, etastart = LP, offset = o,  : 
      NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'
   warning
Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: fitted rates numerically 0 occurred
```

I didn't think that a subset of the data would be necessary for this question, therefore I didn't provide one. But if I't truly is necessary just let me know and I'll create a subset.

All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I've just been experiencing the same problem. There's some discussion around MASS and problems with glm.fit at Andrew Gelman's blog [here](http://andrewgelman.com/2011/05/04/whassup_with_gl/), which might be at least slightly related.

The problem seems to be with the `confint()` function. From the confint manual:

> There are stub methods for classes "glm" and "nls"
>   which invoke those in package MASS which are based on profile
>   likelihoods.
>
> ...
>
> `confint(glm.D93) # needs MASS to be present on the system`
>
> `confint.default(glm.D93)  # based on asymptotic normality`

I find that if I use the `confint.default()` function the problem goes away. I wish I had more of an answer than that.